# How do I get all users that can perform certain AWS actions (e.g. iam-CreateAccessKey, ec2-AssociateIamInstanceProfile)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-policies

Is this possible? If not, maybe I can do it the other way around like getting the AWS actions per user?

I tried the below command but this doesn't have any action info. :(

```
for user in $(aws iam list-users | jq -r '.Users[].UserName'); do echo '{ "Username": "'$user'", "Info": ['; aws iam list-user-policies --user-name $user; echo ','; aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name $user; echo ','; aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name $user; echo '] },'; done > users.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't that simple.

The closest option is to [Test IAM policies with the IAM policy simulator - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html). You can ask it whether a particular user can perform a given Action with particular parameters.

Otherwise, all you can do is parse the policies yourself and try to figure out what they can do.